# Flutter : Errors appearing after updating the Firebase auth package

Tags: flutter

I created the Firebase Auth class a year ago. Now After updating the Dart language and updating the firebase auth package some errors appeared.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Stream<String> get onAuthStateChanged => _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.map(
      (FirebaseUser user) => user.uid,
  );
  // Sign up Email & passowrd
  Future<String> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password, String name) async {
    final currentUser = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
    //updat username
     var userUpdateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
    userUpdateInfo.displayName = name;
    await currentUser.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo);
    await currentUser.reload();
    return currentUser.uid;
  }
  // sign in Email & password
  Future<String> sinInWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password) async {
    return (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password))
        .uid;
  }
  // sign out
  signOut() {
    return _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
}
```

[click here to see error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOoUk.png)

Answer (score 0):

All firebase plugins for flutter since a year ago have a lot of breaking changes you should go to firebase.flutter.dev and check it

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying and searching for more than two weeks The error appears in the code:

```
    //updat username
var userUpdateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();

userUpdateInfo.displayName = name;

await currentUser.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo);
await currentUser.reload();
return currentUser.uid;
```

}

The method 'UserUpdateInfo' isn't defined for  the type 'AuthService'